# Montar html pelo c#

Tags: c#, html

Acredito que tenha uma forma melhor de fazer isso, até porque quando eu fiz fazia todo o sentido agora não intendo mais nada, pois assim fica muito confuso:

Tenho UM campo na tabela que armazena o seguinte conteúdo:

```
Descrição: 
O curso visa capacitar o aluno nas diferentes técnicas de microagulhamento, ensinando quando utilizar os diferentes tipos de agulhas em associação com cosmetologia, nutracêutica e recursos estéticos, Com a prática demonstrativa, o aluno poderá compreender a correta condução do procedimento.

Objetivo: 
Capacitar o aluno na técnica de microagulhamento e em como associar com demais recursos estéticos, cosméticos e nutracêuticos.

Público Alvo:
Farmacêuticos
Médicos
Esteticistas
Biomédicos
Fisioterapeutas
Terapeutas Ocupacionais
Enfermeiros

Conteúdo Programático:
Conceito de microagulhamento
Diferentes técnicas de agulhamento
Indicações das técnicas de agulhamento
Mediação do processo inflamatório
Terapia combinada
Tratamento rejuvenescedor
Tratamento clareador
```

O meu resultado final tem quer ser este:

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="text-align: justify">
    <strong>Descrição:</strong>
    <ul>
        <li>O curso visa capacitar o aluno nas diferentes técnicas de microagulhamento, ensinando quando utilizar os diferentes tipos de agulhas em associação com cosmetologia, nutracêutica e recursos estéticos, Com a prática demonstrativa, o aluno poderá compreender a correta condução do procedimento.
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <strong>Objetivo:</strong>
    <ul>
        <li>Capacitar o aluno na técnica de microagulhamento e em como associar com demais recursos estéticos, cosméticos e nutracêuticos.
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <strong>Público Alvo:</strong>
    <ul class="star_list">
        <li>Farmacêuticos
        </li>
        <li>Médicos
        </li>
        <li>Esteticistas
        </li>
        <li>Biomédicos
        </li>
        <li>Fisioterapeutas
        </li>
        <li>Terapeutas Ocupacionais
        </li>
        <li>Enfermeiros
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <strong>Conteúdo Programático:</strong>
    <ul class="star_list">
        <li>Conceito de microagulhamento
        </li>
        <li>Diferentes técnicas de agulhamento
        </li>
        <li>Indicações das técnicas de agulhamento
        </li>
        <li>Mediação do processo inflamatório
        </li>
        <li>Terapia combinada
        </li>
        <li>Tratamento rejuvenescedor                   
        </li>
        <li>Tratamento clareador                       
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Resultado visual:

[image: Resultado Visual]

Ou seja,

1. Quando existir uma quebra de duas linhas, a próxima linha tem quer em negrito;
2. Quando houver mais que uma quebra de linha, sem ter uma dupla queda de linha, representa uma lista;

A pergunta é: Existe uma forma de montar o `html`, sem utilizar tanto `IF` e `ELSE`?

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="text-align: justify">
     <%
        foreach (var conteudo in conteudos)
        {
          primeiro = true;
          foreach (var topico in conteudo.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
          { 
              if (primeiro)
              {
      %>
      <strong>
      <%
              }
              else
              { 
       %>
       <li>
       <%} %>
       <%=topico %>
       <%if (primeiro)
       {
        primeiro = false; 
        %>
        </strong>
         <%
          if (conteudo.Count(f => f == '\n') > 1)
          {
          %>
                    <ul class="star_list">
                        <%
                      }
                      else
                      { %>
                        <ul>
                            <%} 
                            }
                              else
                              { %>
                    </li>
                    <%} 
                       } %>
                        </ul>
                        <hr />
                        <%} %>
                </div>
```

Comment: Qual é a pergunta?

Comment: Uma melhor forma de montar o html.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo é WebForms ou MVC?

Comment: Usar os controles Web do Framework é uma boa pedida.

Comment: @Maria, WebForms

Comment: Então existe os componentes, por exemplo o `repeater` que é uma boa solução, mas, eu preciso entender no seu caso qual a usabilidade disso e com repeater não precisaria de muitos if ou de nenhum, na verdade não é prática colocar if em webforms, se você me contextualizar melhor eu possa te ajudar a resolver seu problema, só lembrando que tem maluco já querendo fechar a pergunta sua se ainda nem teve tempo hábil ao minimo de uma resposta!

Comment: @Maria, fiz uma edição, acredito que agora está mais claro.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo faça isso com repeater!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via Javascript:

```
function formatarBloco(conteudo)
{
    var resultado = '';
    var blocos = conteudo.split('\n\n');

    blocos.forEach(function(bloco) {
        var partes = bloco.split('\n');

        partes.forEach(function(parte, i) {
            if(i == 0){
                resultado += '<strong>' + partes[0] + '</strong><br/>';

                if (partes.length == 2)
                    resultado += '<ul>';
                else
                    resultado += '<ul class="star_list">';
            }
            else
                resultado += '<li>' + partes[i] + '</li>';

        });

        resultado += '</ul><hr/>';
    });
    return resultado;
}
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddler.](http://jsfiddle.net/t1hzjxvL/1/)

Comment: Muito boom!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Você está montando um elemento `ul`, então meu conselho é usar o controle [BulletedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist(v=vs.110).aspx). Existe um exemplo de como usá-lo ao final da página citada.

Qualquer elemento mais que você queira vai invariavelmente ter um controle correspondente. Por exemplo:

Tabelas: GridView, DataView;
Caixas de texto: TextBox;
Grandes listas de opções com radio: RadioButtonList
Etc., etc. Fica a seu critério pesquisar.

E como esses controles são todos do Framework, você pode deixar a lógica de criação e exibição dos dados no lado do servidor, no Code Behind. Caso contrário, se for pra ficar no cliente mesmo, sugiro usar Javascript.